# How to access the name of an array / object, not the values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, each

I have rewritten a version of each below. In my output I want it to log

```
[['motorbike', 0, vehicles],[['car', 1, vehicles]],[['plane', 2, vehicles]]]
```

However it currently logs the entire contents of the array rather than just the title. How can I get it to provide the the list name instead?

```
function each(collection, callback) {
    if (Array.isArray(collection)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
            callback(collection[i], i, collection);
        }
    } else {
        return collection;
    }
}
var vehicles = ['motorbike', 'car', 'plane'];
var iterationInputs = [];
each(vehicles, function(vehicle, index, list) {
    iterationInputs.push([vehicle, index, list]);
});

console.log(iterationInputs);
```

Comment: There is no "list name"..... Do you want an object and not an array? Maybe I have no clue what you are asking... what are you expecting the log to loo like?>

Comment: I want it to log out  `[['motorbike', 0, vehicles],[['car', 1, vehicles]],[['plane', 2, vehicles]]]` but instead it is logging out `[["motorbike", 0, ["motorbike", "car", "plane"]],["car", 1, ["motorbike", "car", "plane"],["plane", 3, ["motorbike", "car", "plane"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can't access variable names
I think you need to use hash tables ,, this link can help you http://www.mojavelinux.com/articles/javascript_hashes.html